# substract two values from different table and store it in field

Tags: mysql

how to subtract two values from different table and store it in one of the table field.
I have two tables called `allocated_amt` and `spent_amt`, i need to subtract (allocated - spent) and store it in any of the table with the field name `remaining_amt`.

[1st table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUSmT.png)

[2nd table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpX3k.png)

Comment: Please provide your table structure, some sample data and the expected results

Comment: I vote against storing this difference if it might change over time.  Why not just select the difference when you query.

Comment: (Why not just select the difference when you query.) Plz can u explain me with a query?...   Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: share your code trials too.

Comment: Is there a relationship between these 2 tables? I cannot see an allocated amount - should this be approved amount?